# Why am I not able to use OpenGL functions when I include my loader header?

Tags: c++, opengl, function-pointers, c++14

I'm currently trying to create a custom OpenGL function loader so I can start designing my own custom game engine. The header containing all of the loader code is formatted as follows:

```
#ifndef SWOGLL_H_
#define SWOGLL_H_
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/glext.h>
#include <gl/wglext.h>

static PFNGLACTIVESHADERPROGRAMPROC glActiveShaderProgram;
static PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC glActiveTexture;
// ...

static void* GetGLFunctionPointer(const char* functionName)
{
    void* functionPointer = (void*)wglGetProcAddress(functionName);
    if(
        functionPointer == (void*)0x0 ||
        functionPointer == (void*)0x1 ||
        functionPointer == (void*)0x2 ||
        functionPointer == (void*)0x3 ||
        functionPointer == (void*)-0x1
    )
    {
        HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
        functionPointer = (void*)GetProcAddress(module, functionName);
    }
    return functionPointer;
}


static void GenerateGLFunctionPointers()
{
    glActiveShaderProgram = (PFNGLACTIVESHADERPROGRAMPROC)GetGLFunctionPointer("glActiveShaderProgram");
    glActiveTexture = (PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC)GetGLFunctionPointer("glActiveTexture");
    // ...
}
```

If I `#include "SWOGLL.h"` in my `main.cpp` file, the OpenGL functions work fine, assuming I've called `GenerateGLFunctionPointers()` after creating an OpenGL context.

However, if I create a separate file and `#include "SWOGLL.h"`, the OpenGL functions don't work at all, even if the OpenGL context has already been created.

What's the problem here?

Comment: By the way, you should be using `wglGetProcAddress()` instead of `GetProcAddress()`.  The `GetProcAddress()` function is for loading functions from a DLL, and OpenGL is a bit more tricky.  Use `wglGetProcAddress()` to get the correct behavior.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I added `GetProcAddress` as a failsafe in case `wglGetProcAddress` fails, but if it doesn't work with OpenGL functions, then I'll probably remove it.

Comment: "*create a custom OpenGL function loader so I can start designing my own custom game engine*" You do not need to create a custom OpenGL loader for your game engine. There are [plenty to choose from](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library); one of them will take care of your needs.

Comment: Also `LoadLibraryA` will bump the reference count for `opengl32.dll`. That's bad. Instead, you should use `GetModuleHandleA`.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: You should simply not use `GetProcAddress()`, not even as a failsafe.  It is the wrong function, it is for loading from DLLs.  You are not loading from a DLL, you are loading an implementation-specific OpenGL function which might change depending on the OpenGL context.  So `GetProcAddress()` may work sometimes, but you should avoid using it at all.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Ah, thanks for letting me know about that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm aware that there are many OpenGL loaders out there, but I'm choosing to make my own in this situation.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: By switching between `wglGetProcAddress` and `GetProcAddress`, you have the ability to load GL 1.1 functions on Windows and make them look like any other loaded functions, rather than relying on `gl.h`. And those functions *will* be implementation-dependent, since `opengl32.dll` is not provided by any implementation. Other extension loaders do this too; that's where I picked up on it. It regularizes all of the platforms by removing your dependency on `gl.h`, who's contents are not cross-platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring `static` functions and variables in a header file.  Unless you have an exceptionally good reason to do something so bizarre, *don't do that*.

```
static PFNGLACTIVESHADERPROGRAMPROC glActiveShaderProgram;

static void* GetGLFunctionPointer(const char* functionName)
```

This will create a *different* copy of `glActiveShaderProgram`, `GetGLFunctionPointer()`, and everything else declared `static` in every C++ file that includes the header.

Remove `static`, and do one of the following things:

1. Keep the declaration in the header, but move the definition to a C++ file.
2. Keep the declaration and definition in the header, but mark it `inline`.  This does not work with global variables.

The `static` keyword, in this case, makes it so the functions and variables declared `static` have "internal linkage", which means that you get a separate copy of them for every C++ file that defines them.  This is different from declaring a member function `static`, which has a completely unrelated effect.  It is somewhat unfortunate that the keyword `static` means different things in different places.  C'est la vie.

Comment: If I remove `static` and choose either of these options, I get thousands of `LNK2005` linker errors.

Comment: Post the new code so we can find out what went wrong this time.  Is this your first time writing a C++ program with multiple files?

Comment: It's not my first time, but I have very little experience with it. Should I post a new question?

Comment: For this, probably not. The line between "more of the same question" and "different questions about the same code" is not always clear, but I think you can just add to the question in this case.

Comment: I did a little looking online before posting and I seemed to have resolved the issue by marking the declarations of the OpenGL functions, `GetGLFunctionPointer` and `GenerateGLFunctionPointers` as `extern` in the `"SWOGLL.h"` header. I then just created a separate file where I declared the OpenGL pointers and defined `GetGLFunctionPointer` and `GenerateGLFunctionPointers`. The updated code is here: https://github.com/Ethan-Bierlein/SWOGLL

Comment: FYI, you don't need to mark the functions `extern`, that is the default for functions.